# wordpress ajax upload media not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, uploads, linux

I move my wordpress website to another server that is centos7 and apache web server and everything is ok but ajax upload in media not work. it is ok when i did not use ajax but it has problem with ajax and i think the error code is 403
Also i have a reverse proxy server that is kerio

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the access to admin-ajax.php is forbidden (error 403). For some reason, many security plugins are preventing access to admin-ajax.php, even with this file being essential for WordPress to work correctly.

1. If you use some security plugin, check out if it is maybe blocking admin-ajax.php.
2. Check if admin-ajax.php is blocked in .htaccess file (if you use Apache server).
3. Check with your hosting company to examine logs and find out what is blocking admin-ajax.php access.